# How do i recreate new session in Appium automatically, when a session is already terminated because device looses Wi-Fi connection randomly?

Tags: session, appium

Im using Appium V1 15.1, Automating Android device v5.1.1 using python language. I have 40 different appium server sessions running in my machine to test on 40 devices parellel from single python script which has multiprocessing module

I connected to all 40 panels through ADB- WiFi but due to WiFi interference some devices looses Wifi connection randomly and reconnects. when that happens my Appium logs gives me error that "UiAutomator driver shutdown unexpectedly,moving to state stopped and closing the current appium session " but when the devices recovers Wifi i want appium server to recreate new session to continue testing on that particular device
Since i have 40 devices running at a time and devices loose WiFi connection randomly how do i know which device lost connection to restart the Appium session back to continue testing device?

Comment: if u can share code how you are creating connection for all registered adb devices then it would be easy to tell how we can monitor for lost connection and reconnect.

Comment: devicenames = subprocess.Popen("adb devices",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = devicenames.communicate()
    print(output)
    stringValue = output[0].decode("UTF-8")
    #Split the string and read only device id
    devicesconnected = stringValue.split("\r\n", 1)
    mydevice =  devicesconnected[1].split("\r\n")
    for i in range(0, len(mydevice)):
        mydevice[i] = mydevice[i].split("\t")[0] 
    return mydevice